# Not getting back the value I want

Tags: javascript, function, callback

```
let multiMap = function (value, n, cb) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    return cb(value);
  }
};
let result1 = multiMap(7, 2, function (n) {
  return n * 10;
});
console.log(result1); // 700
```

What am I not getting 700? Im confused on how to return the callback twice here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you tried running this code step by step in a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You have returned the value at the first iteration of the `for` loop. You should try something like this-

```js
let multiMap = function (value, n, cb) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    value = cb(value);
  }
  return value;
};

let result1 = multiMap(7, 2, function (n) {
  return n * 10;
});

// Using arrow function with n = 3;
let result2 = multiMap(7, 3, n => n * 10);

console.log(result1); // 700
console.log(result2); // 7000
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop, you can use recursion:

```js
let multiMap = function (value, n, cb) {
  if (n > 0) {
    return multiMap(cb(value), n - 1, cb);
  } else {
    return value;
  }
};

let result1 = multiMap(7, 2, function (n) {
  return n * 10;
});
console.log(result1);
```